# Catching errors from stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to add a new user to table using a SQL Server stored procedure, but it's not being added, and it does not shows any errors, either.

C# code:

```
public void ADD_USER(string firstname, string lastname, string username, string password, string birthdate, string shiftstart, string shiftend, string ssn, string address, int salary, byte[] id_image, byte[] avatar)
{
    DAL.DataAccessLayer DAL = new DAL.DataAccessLayer();
    DAL.Open();

    SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[12];
    param[0] = new SqlParameter("@USERNAME", SqlDbType.VarChar,100);
    param[0].Value = username;
    param[1] = new SqlParameter("@PASSWORD", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
    param[1].Value = password;
    param[2] = new SqlParameter("@FIRSTNAME", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
    param[2].Value = firstname;
    param[3] = new SqlParameter("@LASTNAME", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
    param[3].Value = lastname ;
    param[4] = new SqlParameter("@BIRTHDATE", SqlDbType.Date);
    param[4].Value = birthdate;
    param[5] = new SqlParameter("@ADDRESS", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
    param[5].Value = address;
    param[6] = new SqlParameter("@SSN", SqlDbType.Int);
    param[6].Value = ssn;
    param[7] = new SqlParameter("@SHIFTSTART", SqlDbType.Time);
    param[7].Value = shiftstart;
    param[8] = new SqlParameter("@SHIFTEND", SqlDbType.Time);
    param[8].Value = shiftend;
    param[9] = new SqlParameter("@SALARY", SqlDbType.Int);
    param[9].Value = salary;
    param[10] = new SqlParameter("@ID_IMAGE", SqlDbType.Image);
    param[10].Value = id_image;
    param[11] = new SqlParameter("@AVATAR", SqlDbType.Image);
    param[11].Value = avatar;

    try 
    {
        DAL.executeCommand("ADD_USER", param);
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        Console.Write(ex.Message);
    }

    DAL.close();
}
```

Stored procedure code:

```
CREATE PROC ADD_USER
    @USERNAME VARCHAR(100),
    @PASSWORD VARCHAR(100),
    @FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(100),
    @LASTNAME VARCHAR(100),
    @BIRTHDATE VARCHAR(100),
    @ADDRESS VARCHAR(100),
    @SSN INT,
    @ID_IMAGE IMAGE,
    @AVATAR IMAGE,
    @SHIFTSTART VARCHAR(100),
    @SHIFTEND VARCHAR(100),
    @SALARY INT
AS
    INSERT INTO [CAFE].[dbo].[users] ([username], [password],
                                      [firstname], [lastname], [SSN],
                                      [id_image], [avatar],
                                      [start_working], [shift_start], [shift_end],
                                      [salary], [birth_date], [address])
    VALUES (@USERNAME, @PASSWORD,
            @FIRSTNAME, @LASTNAME, @SSN,
            @ID_IMAGE, @AVATAR,
            CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()), @SHIFTSTART, @SHIFTEND,
            @SALARY, @BIRTHDATE, @ADDRESS)
```

The stored procedure works fine on SQL Server itself, but doesn't add any records from C# code

I tried to trace this issue but I didn't get a result.

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 And Visual Studio 2015

Comment: `@BIRTHDATE` is a `VARCHAR(100)` in the stored procedure but set as a `Date` in the C# code. `@SHIFTSTART` and `@SHIFTEND` are also wrong.

Comment: you might be pointing to the wrong database or confirming records in the wrong database or even the wrong server.

Comment: Maybe catch "Exception" to make sure it isn't a type issue.

Comment: @JasonW Good point. This could be hiding an `InvalidOperationException` which `SqlConnection.Open()` can throw.

Comment: You can also use Sql Server Profiler to see if your c# code is even calling the expected instance and database.

Comment: Sql Server Profiler allows you to monitor the execution of stored procedures

Comment: @LewsTherin I changed birthdate to date, shiftstart and shiftend to time but nothing changed

Comment: @AshrafEldawody As others have mentioned, check your connection strings, change the `catch` block to catch all `Exception`s and if you still can't figure it out, use SQL Server Profiler.

Comment: @LewsTherin i've tried that but all exceptions didn't give any errors , going to use SQL server Profiler now, thanks

Comment: What does your **connection string** look like? Are you using SQL Server **Express** (or **LocalDB**) by any chance? With a `AttachDbFileName=` clause in your connection string?

Comment: Also, please note that the `IMAGE` data type is obsolete. (and 2008r2 is running out of extended support soon)

Comment: How are you testing whether it was added? Are you counting records? 25% of the time the answer to this type of question is 'you're testing the wrong thing'